# Adding a wrapper to an overloaded function

Tags: c#

Say you had a timestamp function and then wanted to create a new function to combine your timestamp and `Console.WriteLine()`, e.g.

```
public static void Write(string msg)
    {
        WriteTimeStamp();
        Console.WriteLine( msg );
    }
```

But the `WriteLine()` method has 18 or so overloads, which will not be reflected in the signature of the wrapper function. How would you have the wrapper take non-strings and pass them on to `WriteLine()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#4.0 you could use a dynamic variable (see [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2010/05/24/using-the-dynamic-keyword-in-c-to-improve-object-orientation.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+PeterRitchiesMvpBlog+%28Peter+Ritchie%27s+MVP+Blog%29)):

```
public static void Write(object msg) 
{
    WriteTimeStamp();
    dynamic dynMsg = msg;
    Console.WriteLine(dynMsg); 
}
```

Comment: Since this lets me also use default parameters, I really like this solution.

Answer (score 5):

You might want the `params` keyword, or alternatively I might be misunderstanding your question:

```
public static void Write(string msg, params object[] args)
{
    WriteTimeStamp();
    Console.WriteLine(msg, args);
}
```

This allows you to specify 0 or more additional arguments of any type, and the `Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])` overload will be called which pretty much handles all the others.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **params** keyword as a method parameter

See [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(VS.71).aspx)